# Remote Xampp Access

Tags: php, xampp

i have installed XAMPP 1.7.4, now my project URL is

http://localhos.host/amu

and my IP is 192.168.0.40

i want to access my XAMPP Project to Another Computer how i do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Configure the web server to listen on your external network interface (Apache is often configured to only listen on localhost by default).
- Open port 80 for inbound connections in the firewall on your computer.
- If you want people outside your LAN to access your server, enable [port forwarding](http://portforward.com/) in your router/gateway, so that port 80 is forwarded to your computer.
- If you use DHCP in your network, configure your DHCP server to give your computer the same address every time (for example, by MAC address).